# WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once. Only in one route

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This error [image]

The weird part is it only exist in a certain part of the app `/foor/bar` but not it `/foo2/bar2`.

I suspect that it hast something to do with that `jQuery` warning above

> :8561Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

but im not sure what causes this. Am using angular `1.5.9` and jQuery `2.1.4`. I also tried switching version but it always failed.

Comment: in the certain part of the app, say `app/foo/bar` , are you using any `<script></script>` tag directly in any template, which may include jQuery code?

Comment: @RajeshDan no, there is no such tag. What's weird about this is that, all `modules` (`controller` and `view` in a folder) are identical to one another. Yet, this one particular route `/foo/bar` is going coocoo. Damn.

Comment: two more explanation may be (first one I've faced earlier),
1. I was using `require` to load the templates, in one case I was requiring a template which was accidentally recursively loading itself (path issue)
2. HTML tag error: Some tag is not closing (forget to close a tag maybe)

Comment: @CENT1PEDE How you fixed this issue?

Comment: @ShrinivasPai I am sorry I forgot this was a very long time ago. :(